# Is our practice often at variance with the psak of the Mishnah Berura as in the brocho on the Talis Godol?

Tags: halacha, blessing, grammar-dikduk, nuschaot, tallit-gadol

[Mishnah Berura, OC 8 (4) [10]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=25) says that the brocho on the Talis Godol is “lehisataif b**e**tzitis” and not as I see in the all my siddurim “lehisataif b**a**tzitis”. Are there many cases where what we do differs from the psak of the Mishnah Berura?

Comment: It certainly does for Sephardim.

Comment: And on a serious note, yes there are. Are you looking for a complete list of minhagim that are different? You will likely find lots of shuls have lots of different minhagim (let alone differences between the US and Israel and other places). I think you need to make your question more specific.

Comment: I believe the Mishna Berura even says not to say "Berich Shemeh" while most Ashkenazim still say it. I think if there is a Minhag that existed before the MB Ashkenazim might keep it (most of the time).

Comment: Interesting, this example you give is the Minhag of Sefaradim (see BI"H S"A Bereshit).

Comment: I've closed this question for the reason @DoubleAA has mentioned: "Are you looking for a complete list of minhagim that are different? You will likely find lots of shuls have lots of different minhagim (let alone differences between the US and Israel and other places). I think you need to make your question more specific." Or, in the words of the stock close reason: "This question is... vague,... overly broad,... and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." If you wish to edit it to something reopenable, by all means do so; ping me with `@msh210`, and I'll be glad to reopen it.